How to use leading zero value from csv field as string value in php precisely?
I have the value fields--mostly having leading zero values (eg. 00566478990), retrieved from .csv file. I use those fields in conditional IF. Unfortunately, the use of leading-zero values behave as same as non leading-zero values in both meet-condition and don't meet condition.
How to solve that problem, I am not sure whether the problem is with my csv file or my code?
Here is part of conditional IF:
//$val[1] is value with leading zero (mostly)
//$param1 is from input form (here I use CI $this->input->post('reg-num');
if($val[1] == $param1){ //
     //some logic go here; 
     // THE PROBLEM is HERE; as for example: I input both 0012345 and 12345 into the form, then,
     echo $val[1]; //the output is 0012345 from two condition. Why is that happen?
}

I expect:
if($val[1] == $param1){ //
     //some logic go here; 
     // as for example: I input both 0012345 into the form, then,
     echo $val[1]; //the output is 0012345 but if I input 12345 it outputs "False" or another logic
}

It seems that, any value leading with zero (eg. 0012345 || 012345 || 0000000...12345) is interpreted as 12345 in my case.

Your observation is correct. You can use strcmp(), which will not make a conversion (eg. remove leading zeros)

You can use strict equality: https://3v4l.org/2nbCq

Thanks a ton @Honk Der hase.
I use strcmp(). It basically compares two given values. It returns 0 when the values are equal.
So, I implemented it on my code:
$check_val=strcmp($val[1], $param1);
if($check_val == '0'){
     //some logic go here; 
     echo $val[1]; 
}

